# How to get value from onetoone relation using request user

Tags: django, one-to-one

im setting the request user in templates using this code, and this code work really good.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ user.name }}
{% else %}
    xxxxxxx
{% endif %}
```

tables:

```
user(model.Models):
    id
    ...

Profile(model.Models):
    user onetoone(user)
    name
    last name
```

my user table have a onetoone relation with Profile and i want to know if i can get a field of Profile table using the request.user or other way to make it, thanks for all.

Comment: Yes, you can. Exactly where are you having trouble?

Comment: hi, thank for the edition and sorry, my question is how?, i can use {{ user.fieldProfile }} directly?

Answer (score 0):

If I rightly understand you are using built-in user model. So we can write:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    ***user*** = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

User.*profile* = property(lambda u: Profile.objects.get_or_create(***user***=u)[0])
```

**views.py**

```
def profile(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = user.*profile*
```

after you can use profile fields like profile.name or other